# How do I use KeyStone from Terminal

Tags: 12.04, openstack

I have installed OpenStack Grizzly on my `Ubuntu Server 12.04` installed in `VMWare`

I want to use `KeyStone` and when I command `keystone user-list`

it give this

```
  Expecting authentication method via
  either a service token, --os-token or env[OS_SERVICE_TOKEN], 
  or credentials, --os-username or env[OS_USERNAME].
```

I want to ask how do I specify these credentials?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I set these environment variables and it works for me.

```
export OS_AUTH_URL=http://192.168.171.131:5000/v2.0/
export OS_TENANT_NAME=admin
export OS_TENANT_NAME=admin
export OS_USERNAME=admin
export OS_PASSWORD=nomoresecrete
```

Answer (score 1):

You should set a few environment variables to let the keystone command know where it should connect to, and what your openstack credentials are.
These environment variables are:
`OS_USERNAME`, `OS_PASSWORD`, `OS_TENANT_NAME`, `OS_AUTH_URL`

You can also set these values in the keystone command line, but environment variables are usually easier.

The openstack dashboard (Horizon) can generate a script file with all of the environment variables you need. If you can log in, go to 'Access and Security'->'API Access' and download the configuration file.

Once you have it, run

```
source /path/to/configuration/file
```

It will prompt you for your password, and then you can run the above command.